# Сравнение элементов массива в ассемблере

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Сравниваются два элемента: (указатель на `a` передан функцией)

```
mov eax, [a]
add eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
mov ebx, [eax]
mov temp_char, ebx
add eax, 1
mov ebx, [eax]
cmp temp_char, ebx
JNE exit
mov [eax], 's'
```

Но в `ebx` почему-то кладется не сам элемент массива, а страшное многозначное число. Почему?

UPD: Это ассемблерная вставка в си. Есть массив, нужно с помощью ассемблерной вставки найти одинаковые элементы и убрать заменить их всех кроме одного, скажем, на `$`. Вот и вся задача. Здесь я пытался просто посмотреть работу сравнения: он должен сравнить второй и третий элементы, в случае совпадения поставить вместо третьего `s`. В переменной я сохранял, потому что `cmp` не захотел сравнивать два регистра.

Comment: **`a`** это ссылка на две ссылки. Причём одна расположена в памяти по адресу `[[a + 1]]`, а этого быть не может, так как 32-хбитный регистр и адресация тоже (иначе была бы инструкция `movzx`).

Comment: Кстати, адрес может содержать смещение, то есть например `[eax + 1]`. И регистры обнулять перед их загрузкой смысла нет. Сохранять где-то в переменной значение тоже бессмысленно, так как есть еще незадействованные регистры общего назначения: `ecx` и `edx`.

Comment: И `mov [eax], 's'` - это не интела синтаксис: пусть сегмент опущен (`ds`/`ss`), но размер операнда не указан. А тип `CHAR` имеет размер один байт, таки образом в него нельзя загрузить дворд (может быть `bl` используется или имена кривые).

Comment: Для начала попробуйте написать код на C. А второй и третий элементы массива сравниваются просто (при условии, что, скажем, в eax - адрес массива и размер элемента - 1 байт): `mov bl, [eax+1]; cmp bl, [eax+2]` Но это - почти  бесполезная информация для решения данной задачи :)

Answer (score 1):

> Есть массив, нужно с помощью ассемблерной вставки в си найти
>   одинаковые элементы и убрать заменить их всех кроме одного, скажем, на
>   '$'

Начнём с самого примитивного алгоритма на C. Будем тупо менять все дубликаты на символ '$', оставив только первые из дублирующихся символов:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char *
find_and_replace_dups( char * data, size_t n, char to )
{
    size_t i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for( j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if( data[i] == data[j] )
            {
                data[j] = to;
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}

#define SIZE ((sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]))-1)
int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "abcdabcdabcdef";

    printf( "%s", find_and_replace_dups( data, SIZE, '$' ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод: **abcd$$$$$$$$ef**

А теперь то же самое на ассемблере. Видимо, нужен Intel, но такого под рукой нет, как и Windows. Поэтому NASM и под Linux: синтаксис поближе будет, а остальное типа `int 80h` - мелочи, основное всё то же самое.

```
; ------------------------------------------
section .data
; ------------------------------------------
data          db  'abcdabcdabcdef'
data_length   equ $-data
; ------------------------------------------
section .text
; ------------------------------------------
global main
main:
    cld
    mov ah, '$'
    mov esi, data
    mov ecx, data_length
    mov edx, ecx
    add edx, esi

for1:
    lodsb
    cmp esi, edx
    je print
    mov ebx, esi

for2:
    cmp al, [ebx]
    jne next1

    mov [ebx], ah

next1:
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx, edx
    jne for2
    jmp for1

print:
    mov ecx, data
    mov edx, data_length
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h
; ------------------------------------------
; That's all, folks!
; ------------------------------------------
```

Вывод тот же, ура! **abcd$$$$$$$$ef**

Ну а как это превратить в инлайн-вставку - уже на самостоятельное осмысление :)

P.S. Ну и до кучи: [тык мышой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/87001/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85).