# Задание матрицы с заданными значениями в Ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Как задать матрицу способом, аналогичным тому, которым задается вектор?

```
DATASG       SEGMENT  PARA  'Data'
MAS1          DB 16 DUP(?)
DATASEG ENDS
;---------------------------------------
CODESG       SEGMENT  PARA  'Code'
BEGIN           PROC          PERENOS
ASSUME  SS: STACKSG, CS:CODESG, DS:DATASG, ES:NOTHING
PUSH       DS
SUB        AX,AX
PUSH       AX  
org 100h;
MAS1 dW -12,342,-1254,10000,56,-2345 ;
lea si, MAS1
```

Comment: точно так же как и вектор. пишете значения первой "строки", потом второй - такой же длины в байтах и т.д. для удобства можно отдельными dw для каждой строки

Comment: Правда ваш DW в середине кода выглядит очень странно. В сегменте данных, сразу при объявлении он бы нормально выглядел. Хотя может ваш ассемблер конечно умный и генерит вместо dw в сегменте кода набор инструкций для задания значений

Comment: Еще радует `org 100h` внутри процедуры, который почти гарантированно поломает нормальную работу программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В простейшем случае все элементы матрицы можно хранить в памяти подряд, тогда объявление матрицы с заданными значениями будет выглядеть так:

```
matrix1 dw 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        dw 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
        dw 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

(отступы добавлены для удобства восприятия, особой смысловой нагрузки не несут)

Эти данные можно будет рассматривать как матрицу 3x5. Адрес элемента с индексами *i*, *j* (индексы считаем от 0) будет `matrix1 + 2*i*5 + j` (где 2 - размер элемента, 5 - длина строки).

Возможны другие варианты реализации, например, сначала идет массив смещений (адресов) строк, а потом уже сами строки. Это реализуется несколько сложнее (через макросы, например). Доступ к конкретному элементу будет выполняться в два этапа: получение адреса строки, потом получение адреса элемента в строке. Такой подход позволяет реализовать "зубчатые" массивы, т.е. массивы с переменной длиной строки, что удобно, например, при создании массива текстовых строк.

Comment: По вашей отметке: ответ был действтиельно не ответ, я его преобразовал в три комментария. В один не входило, пришлось прибегнуть к вуду. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/15096/181472